# $(\mbox{Sh,Sh-map})$ represents the category of sheaves on a stack

Tags: category-theory, higher-category-theory

I'm trying to understand the following theorem, and I think I don't understand the definitions.

Let $(\mathcal{C},J)$ be a site (with a subcanonical topology).  Write $\mathcal{C}/X$ for the groupoid of objects over $X\in \mathcal{C}$.  Let $\mbox{Sh}:\mathcal{C}^{op} \rightarrow \mbox{Gpds}$ be the functor taking $X$ to the category of sheaves on $\mathcal{C}/X$ and isomorphisms of sheaves, and let $\mbox{Sh-map}:\mathcal{C}^{op} \rightarrow \mbox{Gpds}$ be the functor taking $X$ to the category whose objects are sheaf morphisms $\mathscr{F} \rightarrow \mathscr{G}$ and whose morphisms are commuting squares of sheaves determined by isomorphisms $\mathscr{F}_1 \stackrel{\sim}{\rightarrow} \mathscr{F}_2$ and $\mathscr{G}_1 \stackrel{\sim}{\rightarrow} \mathscr{G}_2$.  These are in fact both stacks on $\mathcal{C}$, and moreover they determine a category-object $(\mbox{Sh},\mbox{Sh-map})$ in the category of stacks.

> **Theorem**: The category of sheaves on a stack $\mathscr{M}$ is equivalent to the category of morphisms of stacks $\mathscr{M} \rightarrow (\mbox{Sh,Sh-map})$.  That is, the objects are the 1-morphisms and the morphisms are the 2-morphisms.

I'd like to interpret this to mean that the objects of $Shv(\mathscr{M})$ are associated to 1-morphisms $\mathscr{M} \rightarrow \mbox{Sh}$, and that the morphisms of $Shv(\mathscr{M})$ are associated to 2-morphisms in $Hom_{Stacks}(\mathscr{M},\mbox{Sh})$, which in turn should be the same as 1-morphisms $\mathscr{M} \rightarrow \mbox{Sh-map}$.  But there a number of problems with this.

First, given a sheaf $\mathcal{F} \in Shv(\mathscr{M})$ I'm having trouble constructing a natural transformation $\mathscr{M} \rightarrow \mbox{Sh}$.  Perhaps I shouldn't, but to check this I'm using a test object $X\in \mathcal{C}$.  By Yoneda, an object of $\mathscr{M}(X)$ is the same as a 1-morphism of stacks $f:X\rightarrow \mathscr{M}$, and so I obtain an object of $Sh(X)$ (i.e. a sheaf on $\mathcal{C}/X$) via $(\alpha:Y\rightarrow X) \mapsto \mathcal{F}(f\alpha:Y \rightarrow X \rightarrow \mathscr{M})$.  That's natural enough.  Again by Yoneda, a morphism in $\mathscr{M}(X)$ is a 2-morphism between maps $f,g:X\rightarrow \mathscr{M}$ of stacks, i.e. a section $s:X\rightarrow X\times_\mathscr{M} X$ of the projection from the 2-category fiber product.  Out of this, I'm supposed to construct a natural transformation from the sheaf $(\alpha:Y\rightarrow X) \mapsto \mathcal{F}(f\alpha:Y \rightarrow X \rightarrow \mathscr{M})$ to the sheaf $(\alpha:Y\rightarrow X) \mapsto \mathcal{F}(g\alpha:Y \rightarrow X \rightarrow \mathscr{M})$.  But the only structure in place to give me such a thing is a morphism in $Stacks/\mathscr{M}$ between $f\alpha$ and $g\alpha$, and I don't see how to construct this.

Second, a 2-morphism between 1-morphisms $f,g\in Hom_{Stacks}(\mathscr{M},\mbox{Sh})$ is a section $s:\mathscr{M} \rightarrow \mathscr{M} \times_{\mbox{Sh}} \mathscr{M}$.  Thus for any $(\alpha:X\rightarrow \mathscr{M})\in \mathscr{M}(X)$, we get an object $(\alpha,\beta:X \rightarrow \mathscr{M},\varphi:f\alpha \stackrel{\sim}{\rightarrow} g\alpha)\in (\mathscr{M}\times_{\mbox{Sh}}\mathscr{M})(X)$.  On the other hand, a 1-morphism $\mathscr{M} \rightarrow \mbox{Sh-map}$ is for each $\alpha:X \rightarrow \mathscr{M}$ an arbitrary morphism on sheaves on $\mathcal{C}/X$.  These can't be the same.

By the way, I've tried to do (what I think is) the right thing and work out the sheaf in $Shv(\mbox{Sh})$ associated to the 1-morphism $\mbox{Id}:\mbox{Sh} \rightarrow \mbox{Sh}$, following Yoneda and all.  From the above, it's easy to see what this sheaf should do to morphisms $X\rightarrow \mbox{Sh}$ from a representable stack.  But it appears that I need to make choices if I want to say what it does to arbitrary morphisms of stacks $\mathscr{N} \rightarrow \mbox{Sh}$.  Perhaps instead I should take a limit or colimit over its application to the full subcategory of representable stacks over $\mathscr{N}$?

Comment: I've removed the stacks tag because it is somewhat ambiguous whether the tag should apply to the category theoretical one, the algebraic geometric one, or perhaps the computer science one. (Also it is probably too specific a tag for this site). BTW, since you are asking about 2-categories, you may want to tag with the (higher-category-theory) tag?

Comment: @Willie: Thanks Willie -- I wasn't even aware that stacks were a CS term (although perhaps I should've known, considering the name of this family of websites!).  Also, aren't algebro-geometric stacks just a special case of category-theoretic stacks?

Comment: Given the lack of answers here, I've reposted: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/70022/mboxsh-sh-map-represents-the-category-of-sheaves-on-a-stack

Comment: Yes, the AG stacks is a special case of the category theoretic ones. But I assume that the questions one may want to ask about the AG stacks are perhaps likely to be of a different nature from the ones about the category ones?

Comment: Maybe...?  They seem pretty interconnected.  But I guess if I knew, I'd probably be able to answer my own question!